# send from data and image data with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send my form data and image data with ajax but I can only send one of them with my code.

My Javascript code:

```
$("#advertising_form2").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formObj = $("#advertising_form2");
    var formData = formObj.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/php-ajax-upload.php",
        type: "POST",            
        data:new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,             
        processData:false,        
        success: function(data)   
        {
            alertify.success(data);
        }
    });
```

`new FormData(this)` in the ajax parameters contains image data to be sent with ajax.

`var formData` contains form data to be sent with ajax.

With the above code I can only send either `new FormData(this)` or `formData`. How can I send both?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. `new FormData(this)` already contains the same data that is in `serialize()` with exception you can't serialize files